# Не работает пагинация PagedList, MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Я использую PagedList для постраничного отображения товаров на странице, страницы создаються при помощи хелпер-метода Html.PagedListPage, однако вне зависимости от того какую страницу я выбираю, значению page в контроллере присваиваться 1(будто значение страницы null).Код контроллера ниже.

```
public ActionResult Drilling(int? page)
    {
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        IEnumerable<Group> groups = context.Groups;
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categories = from item in context.Categories
                                                 select new SelectListItem { Text = item.CategoryName, Value = item.Id.ToString() };

        var temp = context.Items.ToList();

            CatalogViewModel basemodel = new CatalogViewModel()
            {
                Categories = categories,
                Groups = groups, 
                Items = temp.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize)
            };
            return View(basemodel);
    }
```

Представление:

```html
@model SR.Models.CatalogViewModel
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@{
    int iterator = Model.Items.Count - 1;
    ViewBag.Title = "Drilling";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/shopcatalog.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="search">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Drilling","Production", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "search-form" }))
        {
            <table id="search-options">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBox("Name", "", new { id = "get-name", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Название товара" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Найти" id="search-button" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.Groups)
                        {
                            <div class="radio">
                                <p style="display:inline">@item.Name</p>
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedGroup, item.Id, new { @class = "group-radio" })
                            </div>
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td id="select-td">
                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCategories, Model.Categories, new { id = "select", @class = "list-group" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </div>

    <div class="items-list">
        <table class="items-table">
            <tbody>
                @for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    if(iterator == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="catalog-item">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="item-img">
                                    <img src=@Model.Items[iterator].Image alt="Изображение товара"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="item-description">
                                    <a href="#" class="item-title">@Model.Items[iterator].Name</a>
                                    <p>@Model.Items[iterator].Description</p>
                                    <p>Price: @Model.Items[iterator--].Price</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="pages">
        <div class="pages-wrap">
           @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Items, page => Url.Action("Drilling", new { page }))
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Заметил что данный метод создает разметку с пустыми ссылками:

```html
<div class="pages">
        <div class="pages-wrap">
           <div class="pagination-container">
               <ul class="pagination">
                   <li class="PagedList-skipToPrevious"><a href="" rel="prev">«</a</li>
                   <li><a href="">1</a></li><li><a href="">2</a></li>
                       <li class="active"><a>3</a></li>
                       <li><a href="">4</a></li>
                       <li class="PagedList-skipToNext"><a href="" rel="next">»</a</li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема и как это можно исправить!

Comment: А вы проверяли значение `int? page` при входе в метод? Может там все время `null`?

Comment: Да, так и есть, однако по прежнему не понятно почему, так как в url.action передается параметр page.

Comment: Попробуйте так

`@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.Items, page => Url.Action("Drilling", new { page }))`

Comment: Увы, но ничего не изменилось, тем более что еще в коде контроллера я использовал метод ToPagedList, поэтому привидение типов избыточно.

Comment: `@model PagedList.IPagedList<SR.Models.CatalogViewModel>` а если так.

Comment: Учитывая что модель это не класс с набором свойств, а класс с несколькими списками разных классов то такой вариант совсем не применим.